# Spring Kafka Stream reactive

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Spring team,

I currently use `reactive-kafka` which works great. But If I have to use `kafka-streams`, is there any `reactive` version for it or Is there any reactive version for `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not; with Kafka Streams, Spring is not involved with the data flow at runtime; it is only involved in setting up the streams using normal Spring techniques; once the stream is started, it is all `kafka-streams`.

A similar situation would apply to reactor-kafka; so it has no support for Kafka Streams at all.

Comment: Reactive and Kafka Streams use different programming models. While the former uses a micro-batching approach, Kafka Streams uses a per-record processing strategy and does not need things like back pressure, etc. It does not make sense to mix both paradigms.

Comment: @sobychacko, consider this scenario - we use kafka-streams library.. for every event we need to do some processing and requires db entry for which we use  R2DBC. so what do you think it will happen here ? should we block the db calls? It is a big no. what is your suggestion? sometimes we need to mix..

Comment: I am not a Kafka Streams expert, by any means, but I would say don't use Streams in that case; aside from the fact that it starts with a non-reactive consumer, except for with the simplest of topologies, it has lots of internals (writing/reading from intermediate topics, RocksDB etc) and none of those are reactive.

Comment: Ya, I agree with Gary on that. In that case, don't use Kafka Streams, but start with a regular Kafka Consumer or use the new reactive Kafka binder-based consumer.

Comment: @GaryRussell & soby - ok. I just wanted to get that confirmed from either of you. then i stick with reactive-kafka. (sorry for the shameless request - if you could prioritize this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2695 - it would be great :) )

Comment: I mentioned this mainly because of the in-built transactional support "kafka-streams" provide which is kind of missing as of now in the spring-cloud-stream reactive binder. It would be a great feature to have.